# Can elements such as <h1-h6> and <p> be used as form input if they are given names and values?

Tags: html, forms

Would something like this work?

```
<form action='test.php' method='post'>
    <p name='tester' value='32'>thirty-two</p>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Well I'm in the middle of a project and I was attempting to do this, but I ran into some issues.  I'm not sure if it isn't possible or if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: What issues? Details....

Comment: Why would you want to do that? How could the browser know what you want there? Would you ask for a hotdog in a restaurant and expect to get s salad?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that'll work but you can use a hidden field  or use ajax to send your query string

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "http://somesite.com/test.php", 
    async: true
    data: {
        tester: $("tester").val()
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

Forms will only submit the input type tags.